# Reverse a Doubly Linked List between the given nodes

Tags: c++, reverse, doubly-linked-list

Trying to reverse a linked lists elements given pointers to given nodes in the linked list. 
For example, i would be given a pointer to the 4th and a pointer to the 7th nodes in a linked list and would have to reverse the nodes between these nodes. Here's some relevant code that doesn't work:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::reverse( ListNode * & startPoint, ListNode * & endPoint ){

  if (startPoint == NULL)  
    return;

  if (startPoint->prev != NULL)
    startPoint->prev->next = endPoint;

  if (endPoint->next != NULL)
    endPoint->next->prev = startPoint;

  ListNode * curr = startPoint;
  ListNode * temp = startPoint;

  while(curr != endPoint)
  {
    temp = curr->next;
    curr->next = curr->prev;
    curr->prev = temp;
    curr = temp;
  }

  temp = endPoint->next;
  endPoint->next = endPoint->prev;
  endPoint->prev = temp; 

  temp = startPoint->next;
  startPoint->next = endPoint->next;
  endPoint->prev = startPoint->prev;

  temp = startPoint;
  startPoint = endPoint;
  endPoint = temp;

}
```

This code compiles but doesn't perform the reverse nodes properly and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you point at the failure points? What you do get? It's not a code review, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried coding this, but algorithmically this should be quite fast;

1) first from all nodes between the start and end position of your sublist swap the values for `prev` and `next`. This will invert the order of all nodes in between. Leaving only the edge nodes.

2) After swapping the next and prev at all position also swap the updated next from the original starting node with the updated prev from the original ending node. Now those nodes will point to the correct rest of the sequence.

3) for management also update the nodes just outside the sequence to point correctly.

**An example** (node is shown as "NODE(PREV, NEXT)")

```
A(0,B) - B(A,C) - C(B,D) - D(C,E) - E(D,F) - F(E,-)
```

reversing node 1 - 4 (B - E)

First step:

```
A(0,B) - B(C,A) - C(D,B) - D(E,C) - E(F,D) - F(E,-)
```

2nd

```
A(0,B) - B(C,F) - C(D,B) - D(E,C) - E(A,D) - F(E,-)
```

3rd

```
A(0,E) - B(C,F) - C(D,B) - D(E,C) - E(A,D) - F(B,-)
```

And now to visualize the order:

```
A(0,E) - E(A,D) - D(E,C) - C(D,B) - B(C,F) - F(B,-)
```

And there it is, reversed the middle 4 nodes.

Comment: I believe this is what my code does, yet it is unable to reverse the list properly...

Comment: It is a bit hard to read, would be easier if you actually used std::swap. But anyways, you only do the very first step, not the 2nd and third. Notice the chances from B(C,A) & E(F,D) to B(C,F) & E(A,D)